# axis2 WS in Websphere 8 - JVMVRFY013

Tags: websphere, apache-axis, java-ee-6, axiom

I have a classloading issue in the following project setup:
our EAR contains multiple WARs, two of which are relevant, let's call them web and ejb. We are using Websphere 8.
Now, the ejb.war contains a number of webservices, one of them being newly developed, - some of the classes in ejb.war are generated by axis2 actually.
To invoke this ws, and process the response in the web.war, we'll have to include some jars in the EAR, and adjust the manifests of each war. (?)

I included the axiom-api-1.2.13.jar into the EAR file, and added to the manifest of both web and ejb WARS. It is needed to process the response, which contains a Base64EncodedFileType object.

Now I get the an exception containing the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=ch/teledata/ws/schema/bisv3_6/Request ...
```

I found this error mentioned here http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html - it's a known issue regarding webshpere and axis2. I modified the classLoader of WAS as mentioned, but it doesn't solve the problem. The site mentions an axis2.xml, which no matter where I include in the wars / ear, it doesn't have an effect. Has anybody encountered a problem like this? What might be still missing?

Maybe I'm not inlcuding another axis2 jar, which would read in the configs? Also, I'm not sure if I have to include axiom.jar into the EAR but rather the ejb.WAR.

I'm totally out of ideas where to look for the problem, so don't hesitate to throw questions / directions to me.

If u've read this far, thx for ur time!

The complete stacktrace is here (the method which calls the wsStub is invoked from the web tier):

```
2/25/14 11:49:36:820 CET] 00000021 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Faces Servlet]: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.handleLifecycleException(FacesServlet.java:245)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:301)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.daimler.flsc.fec.web.filter.SerializeRequestFilter.doFilter(SerializeRequestFilter.java:67)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at ch.nevis.jcan.optrace.web.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:115)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3704)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at 

com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.uti

l.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Error calling action method of component with id main_form:testSearchButton
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:296)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:253)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:466)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:151)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.ELException: /view/request/customer.xhtml @492,86 action="#{customerBean.test}": javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: java.lang.Exception: See nested Throwable
    at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:82)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:57)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /view/request/customer.xhtml @492,86 action="#{customerBean.test}": javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: java.lang.Exception: See nested Throwable
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:74)
    at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:78)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: java.lang.Exception: See nested Throwable
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=ch/teledata/ws/schema/bisv3_6/Request, method=getOMElement(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMFactory;)Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMElement;, pc=0
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
    at com.daimler.flsc.services.impl.BusinessInformationServiceBean.callPersonSearch(BusinessInformationServiceBean.java:194)
    at com.daimler.flsc.business.services.dispatchers.BusinessInformationServiceDispatcher.callPersonSearch(BusinessInformationServiceDispatcher.java:68)
    at com.daimler.flsc.business.services.interfaces.EJSRemote0SLBusinessInformationServiceBean_7e0deb6d.callPersonSearch(EJSRemote0SLBusinessInformationServiceBean_7e0deb6d.java)
    at com.daimler.flsc.business.services.interfaces._BusinessInformationService_Stub.callPersonSearch(_BusinessInformationService_Stub.java)
    at com.daimler.flsc.business.services.delegates.BusinessInformationServiceBusinessDelegate.callPersonSearch(BusinessInformationServiceBusinessDelegate.java:55)
    at com.daimler.flsc.fec.web.control.CustomerBean.test(CustomerBean.java:3194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:266)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:296)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:253)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:466)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.daimler.flsc.fec.web.filter.SerializeRequestFilter.doFilter(SerializeRequestFilter.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at ch.nevis.jcan.optrace.web.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:115)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3704)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that the error occurs when the class loader attempts to load an ADB generated class (probably used by an Axis2 Web service client). If you want to do that, then you also need to include the relevant Axis2 JARs in your application. Basically, you need to include all the libraries that you would also need to run the code outside of WebSphere. If you then configure the class loader with `PARENT_LAST`, then it should work.

The change in `axis2.xml` on the other hand is only necessary if your application attempts to use Axis2 modules (e.g. for WS-Addressing).

Comment: Thx for the answer!
Indeed the cause of this was that I assumed there is a kind of isolation between application and websphere's internal classes. Once we included all the necessary axis2/lib jars, it worked.

Before that, actually the webservice calls worked as long as there wasn't a Base64EncodedFileType in the response, because websphere allowed the use of it's internal axis2 classe. So much for isolation.

Comment: Yes, PARENT_LAST gives preference to the classes in your application, but it  indeed doesn't isolate your application from WebSphere's internal classes.